# CSS Class Referencing in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="navigation">            
   <ul class="top-level">
       <li><a href="./Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using the following CSS class on it:

```
<style type="text/css">
#navigation { font-size:0.75em; width:150px; }
#navigation ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
#navigation li { list-style: none; }

ul.top-level { background:#666; }
}
</style>
```

How can I move the CSS code into a separate .css file and reference it in HTML?
I tried using:

```
<div id="navigation">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Styles.css"/>
                <ul class="top-level">
                ...
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Note to all: There is no closing slash for the link element in HTML.

Comment: @Rob: Not true — [*if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/).*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags) — it is pointless and optional but it exists.

Comment: @Quentin Which proves my point. I'm aware of that note but didn't want to get too technical considering ... I guess I should have said "There is no need for ..."

Answer (score 0):

Move `<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Styles.css"/>` to the head or before the `<div id="navigation">`. Like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Styles.css"/>
</head>
```

Or:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Styles.css"/>
<div id="navigation">
         <ul class="top-level">
```

But it's better to move it to the head as it's easier to manage. Also check if the path `CSS/Styles.css` is correct.

Comment: I tried putting that link tag in my header.
I noticed that the head tag already has a link tag in there, so now my head tag looks like this:
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Styles.css"/>
</head>

But it doesn't work. Does it have something to do with other CSS classes being in the Styles.css file?

Comment: Make sure the path to your css file is valid. Also, in comments you can show code by putting it inbetween two ` characters `like so`.

Comment: @user2261573: if it's already there, should not duplicate it. Remove your redundant one in the code. And check if the path `CSS/Styles.css` is correct (points to the file on your server).

Comment: @user2261573: another thing to check is if you have many definitions for your style. For example: check if `#navigation` is in both `CSS/Styles.css` and `StyleSheet.css`

Comment: I know the path is correct.
Now I've put the CSS code in that StyleSheet.css file to keep things simple.
However it's still not working.
Here is my code so far in site.master:

``<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
</head>``
...
``<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 150px; background-color: #CCFFFF">
            <div id="navigation">
                
                <ul class="top-level">
                    <li><a href="./Default.aspx">Home</a></li>``

Comment: In StyleSheet.css:
``.addButtonStyle
{
    border: 2px solid #003399;
    background-color: #B9D1F4;
    color: #003399;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-spacing: 50px;
}

#navigation { font-size:0.75em; width:150px; }
#navigation ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
#navigation li { list-style: none; }
 
ul.top-level { background:#666; }``

Comment: @user2261573: check if there are other duplicate styles in other places. The easiest way to do it is to check it on browser using browser developer tool

Answer (score 0):

the link tag goes in the HEAD Tag so you need

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
```

and of course make sure that the relative path that you use is in the same folder as the html document

Comment: is StyleSheet.css in the same directory as your html file? if not you need the relative path to StyleSheet.css, or the absolute path to it.

Comment: Got it working!
My mistake was that I was putting different classes in the one css file, I used a separate file and put the one class in there and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the SEO-conscious person, it is actually best practice to put your CSS file in the same folder as your html, if possible. So ideally, you would want:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
```

This Will help you keep a flatter file structure, as a browser has one less subfolder to crawl to when loading your page.

Comment: You are talking about directories ("folders") but referencing the structure of the elements in the document. Directories/folders are on the server and contain files. The elements you are talking about are markup inside the document being served.

Answer (score -1):

Got it working!
My mistake was that I was putting different classes in the one css file, I used a separate file and put the one class in there and it worked fine.